# NMR splitting of equivalent, but separated protons

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

I’ve been trying to understand why equivalent sets of protons that are coupled behave as equivalent to a single coupled pair. For example in the spectrum for Diethyl ether: [image: Ether NMR]
Both groups of Hb are split by both groups of Ha resulting in a quartet.
However shouldn’t the Ha protons be independent of each other resulting in 7 possible unique spin configuration? Why is this not the case?

Comment: The two ethyl groups are identical and the methylene protons are enantiotopic, i.e., identical. Thus, n + 1 = 3 where n = 2, a triplet. The spins are up-up, up-down, down-up, down-down. The second and third spins are identical. The intensities of the methyl triplet are 1:2:1.